# Better way to loop through grabbing user details in Mongoose/MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have this code:

```
app.get('/notifications/:id', function(req, res) {
  Notification.find({
    userId: req.params.id
  }, '_id type initiatorId', function(err, notifications) {
    if (err) return;
    // grab all users by the `initiatorId` 
  });
});
```

`notifications` will look like this:

```
[
{
    initiatorId: 1
},
{
    initiatorId: 2
},
{
    initiatorId: 3
}
]
```

However, I need to grab the user details from the `/users` collection for each of these `initiatorId`s. What would be the best way to do that to produce this structure:

```
[
{
    initiatorId: 1,
    user: {
        name: 'john'
    }
},
{
    initiatorId: 2,
    user: {
        name: 'larry'
    }
},
{
    initiatorId: 3,
    user: {
        name: 'moe'
    }
}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a reference in your Notification schema, and then populate it, as per the [Mongoose Docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema   = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId,

var notificationSchema = new Schema({
  initiator: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
});

var Notification = mongoose.model('Notification', notificationSchema);
```

You can then use Mongoose's [query populate method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate):

```
app.get('/notifications/:id', function(req, res) {
  Notification
    .find({ initiator: req.params.id })
    .select('_id type initiatorId')
    .populate('initiator')
    .exec(function(err, notifications) {
      if (err) return handleError(err);
      // do something with notifications
    });
});
```

However, I'm slightly confused why the id is a user id (and not a notification id) – if I were using this API that would confuse me.

This doesn't get you **exactly** the data structure you wanted, but I think it's more like the "right" way, if there is such a thing.

Comment: This is my Notification schema:

`var notificationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  userId: String, // who's it for?
  type: String, 
  initiatorId: String, // who sent the notification
  read: Boolean,
  date: Date
});`